# CSS transitions height input element

Tags: html, css

I have a input element that grows to the right when a user clicks in the box.

```css
.search {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  text-align: left;
}
.search:focus {
  width: 250px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>/">
  <input class="search" type="search" value="" name="s" id="s">
</form>
```

The idea is that the input element grows from 20px to 250px. The problem has nothing to do with the transitions not working :-)

The problem is that the inputbox is very small in height. Whatever I try it just won't get bigger:

See a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dxyzw14m/)

Comment: You should probably want to use a `textarea` rather than `input type="text"` as this would allow resizing. (currently input only allows single line text as it is)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using input type `search`, and it won't accept height. 
But adding `-webkit-appearance:textfield;` would allow you to add padding to increase height, or set height manually.

Comment: Yes. Thank you that was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Added `height:100px` to the `.search` and it grew bigger for me.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q2ftaf8h/)

```
.search {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    text-align:left;
    height:100px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

**Working code snippet**

```css
.search {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  text-align: left;
  height:100px;
}
.search:focus {
  width: 250px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>/">
  <input class="search" type="search" value="" name="s" id="s">
</form>
```

Comment: I was going to add the exact same answer. It works for me too.

Comment: I use chrome browser but it won't get bigger. Firefox does work!

Comment: Thnx but it's a searchform

Comment: @Interactive I'm using chrome as well and for me, it grows bigger in the fiddle

Comment: @Simplicity Wow that's weird. Mine just won't

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `line-height` to set the input height:

**EDIT:** @wellagain answer is the right one, there is a bug with chrome and search input.

```css
.search {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 50px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  text-align: left;
}

.search:focus {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input class="search" type="search">
</form>
```

I also simplified your example.

1. Vendor prefixes for transitions are not really needed now. You can
   use [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=transition) as reference.
2. Focus styles inherit rules from the default styles. So you just need to define the properties that actually change.